# Not understanding how this works neededChar[s1[i]] = (neededChar[s1[i]] || 0) + 1;

Tags: javascript, data-structures, hashmap

So I was solving leetcode questions and was going over the discussions to compare my solutions.

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/

I wasn't sure how this part worked clearly

```js
    let neededChar = {}; 
    for (let i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
         neededChar[s1[i]] = (neededChar[s1[i]] || 0) + 1;
    }
```

I assumed this part basically meant this, but it ends up giving an error on leetcode.

```js
neededChar[s1[i]] = neededChar[s1[i]] ? neededChar[s1[i]]++  : 0;
```

or

```js
if(neededChar[s1[i]]){
neededCharp[s1[i]]++;
}else{
needChar[s1[i]] = 0;
}
```

How is it different?

Answer (score 1):

When you decode it to ternary operator, the statement should be

```
neededChar[s1[i]] = neededChar[s1[i]] ? neededChar[s1[i]]++  : 1;
```

notice the 1. When there is not key-value pair for the current character, the current characters gets added to the object with a value 1.

The initial statement

```
 neededChar[s1[i]] = (neededChar[s1[i]] || 0) + 1;
```

was performing an OR operation on neededChar[s[i]] and 0.

Case 1:- s1[i] key exists in the object neededChar in this case, the OR operation returns 0 and then 1 gets added.

Case 2:- s1[i] key doesn't exist in the object neededChar in this case, the OR operation returns the value for neededChar[s1[i]] ,and then 1 gets added.